# What is the difference between rails structure.sql and schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am aware that schema.rb file is a ruby file and it get created and modified when a rake migration is run, but what about the structure.sql.

I have seen in some projects schema.rb and in others structure.sql and in some both files, where do they configure which file to create.

What exactly is the difference between the two.

Is structure.sql generated is specific to a particular DB.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378123/rails-rake-dbstructureload-vs-rake-dbschemaload

Comment: Also good info here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Comment: Also, be aware that Heroku might not accept structure.sql... SEE http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2016/02/good-reasons-to-replace-dbschemarb-with.html and https://help.heroku.com/AHH2KNSR/why-do-i-get-postgres-extension-errors-when-i-run-rake-db-structure-load-or-rake-db-setup

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The main difference is that `schema.rb` is a Ruby representation of the database, and it is generally database-agnostic. `structure.sql` instead is a SQL representation of the database and it depends on the specific database you selected.

You only use the structure if you have specific database features that you need and that can't be represented by the `schema.rb`. For example, in the past some people replaced `schema.rb` with `structure.sql` in order to use PostgreSQL JSONB fields or foreign key constraints at database level.

Both features are now supported in the migrations, therefore you don't need to switch to `structure.sql` anymore (in these cases).

In general, I suggest you to use the `schema.rb`.

Comment: Adding a reference since this question rates pretty highly in certain searches: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps The db/schema.rb can't express triggers, sequences, stored procedures, check constraints or composite foreign keys (but as noted by Simone, the features such as jsonb for are represented)

Comment: Also schema.rb won't contain things like Postgres views, functions, or any other DB-specific constructs not supported by the Ruby DSL, while structurel.sql will create a perfect copy of the DB structure (SEE https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you)

Comment: Should we get rid of our schema.rb once we switch to structure.sql? Also once using structure.sql if we switch branches without rolling back new migrations from the previous branch is there an easy command to get the current branches structure?

Comment: For more reference pls check this (https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html). Very nicely mentioned everything you should know.